# How to create keystore and truststore

Tags: java, ssl, openssl, keystore

I have a curl request that works correctly:

```
curl -v -X POST --cacert ca.pem --cert tls.crt --key tls.key --data ... -H 'Content-Type: application/json' https://...
```

All options cacert, cert and key are required. How can I create a keystore and truststore from files ca.pem, tls.crt and tls.key to use in my project?

Thank you!

I found only isolated uses of pem or crt files.

Comment: [JSSE Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/security/java-secure-socket-extension-jsse-reference-guide.html#GUID-93DEEE16-0B70-40E5-BBE7-55C3FD432345)